# Is it possible to initialize a static array using a ternary operator in an initializer?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, ternary-operator, constant-expression

Is it possible to initialize a static array with a ternary operator in an initializer?
For example:

```
// Array of functions 
static const Callback_t CallbackArray[] =
{
    GenConfig,
    GenInfo,
    /* here is the ternary operator to chose a callback */
    Test() ? Config : NULLConfig,   
};
```

where Test() is a function that returns a 0 or 1

```
// somewhere else in the code
int gVar = 0;

int TEST(void)
{
    return gVar;
}
```

Comment: Yes. It's perfectly valid. So long as `Test()` s a macro

Comment: Have you *tried* it? Did it work? If not, what errors did you get?

Comment: I think the only problem here is `Test()` since functions aren't constant expressions. If not for that, the code should be ok.

Comment: Test() is a function,as i wrote, not a macro. and it seems to work, but i dont understand how,
 because Test() check a global variable

Comment: In the initialization, code uses `Test()`.    There is a  function called `TEST()`.  `TEST()` is not the same as `Test()`.  Post _true_ code.  As is, it is unclear what is being asked.

Answer (score 3):

If the array does not have static storage duration then the operator can be used as an initializer expression.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals.

Take into account that you may not declare an array of functions but you may declare an array of pointers to functions.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( void ) { puts( "f"); }
void g( void ) { puts( "g"); }

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 1, y = 2;

    void ( *fp[] )( void ) = { x < y ? f : g };

    fp[0]();

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
f
```

If a function type is too complicated you can introduce a typedef for it. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( void ) { puts( "f"); }
void g( void ) { puts( "g"); }

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 1, y = 2;

    typedef void F( void );

    F * fp[] = { x < y ? f : g };

    fp[0]();

    return 0;
}
```

You can use the conditional operator to initialize an array with static storage duration. The problem is that the condition must be a constant expression that is not always suitable. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( void ) { puts( "f"); }
void g( void ) { puts( "g"); }

typedef void F( void );

F * fp[] = { 1 ? &f : &g };

int main(void) 
{
    fp[0]();

    return 0;
}
```

From the C Standard (6.6 Constant expressions)

> 9 An address constant is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue
>   designating an object of static storage duration, or a pointer to **a
>   function designator**; it **shall be created explicitly using the
>   unary & operator** or an integer constant cast to pointer type, or
>   implicitly by the use of an expression of array or function type. The
>   array-subscript [] and member-access . and -> operators, the address &
>   and indirection * unary operators, and pointer casts may be used in
>   the creation of an address constant, but the value of an object shall
>   not be accessed by use of these operators.

Comment: Nothing in your examples has static storage duration though? Didn't you mean to declare the function pointer array at file scope?

Comment: Okay that makes more sense since the OP seem to also have an array of function pointers with static storage duration. This shows that the conditional operator isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `CallbackArray` array has static storage duration (i.e. because of `static` keyword or it might have been placed outside any function), which implies, that it must be initialized with constant expressions.

Here, the conditional operator `?:` does not yield constant expression (because it contains function call), hence the code is is invalid.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. I can't find anything in 6.5.15 supporting your statement. Source? Also `static const int foo = 1 ? 1 : 0;` compiles just fine with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @Lundin: I believe it is C11 6.7.9/4 `All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.`.

Comment: Yes but that doesnt prove that all operands and the result of the conditional operator cant be constant expressions.

Comment: @Lundin: You are right with that, the original answer was incorrect. Neverthless, the key point is still valid. C11 6.6/3 says `Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **initialize** the contents of a `static` array based on a function.

But make another function to choose...

```
typedef returntype (*fxtype)(parmtypes);

fxtype choose(void) {
    return Test() ? Config : NULLConfig;
}

static const Callback_t CallbackArray[] =
{
    GenConfig,
    GenInfo,
    choose,   
};
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but to be a proper replacement, doesn't `choose()` have to call the correct function?  That is, the intended code would use `(*CallbackArray[2])()` and expect the function to be called, so your substitute should be more like `return Test() ? Config() : NULLConfig();`?